# Get data for every day/week/month

Tags: laravel

There is a table of users with the creation date field. How to get data between two dates with and sum up the amount for a day/week/month.
For example:
Date from 2021-10-01 to 2022-02-01
If by days, then output:
2021-10-01 - 50 users
2021-10-02 - 30 users
2021-10-03 - 10 users
...
2022-02-01 - 140 users

If by week:
2021-10-01 - 2021-10-07 - 270 users
2021-10-08 - 2021-10-15 - 370 users
...
if by month
2021-10-01 - 2021-11-01 - 3000 users
2021-11-01 - 2021-12-01 - 2500 users

It is important that the date is returned in the format 2021-10-01

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you need to count users `created_at` between two dates you can do it like this:

```
$startdate = your_first_date; (of week or month or w/e)
$enddate = your_second_date; (of week or month or w/e)

$user_count = Users:whereBetween('created_at', [$startdate, $enddate])
              ->count();
```

This way you get all users where `created_at` is between your desired dates and with the `count()` you get an integer back with the number of found entries.

You could add a second condition like so:

```
$user_count = Users:whereBetween('created_at', [$startdate, $enddate])
                  ->where('status', '=', 1)
                  ->count();
```

This way you can add any condition you like, in my example it would be some kind of status that indicated if the user is active or not